# Is this a bug in scala.xml.Elem?

Tags: xml, scala

Mapping a Set[String] to attributes of a Set[Elem] works fine with one attribute, but seems to fail with multiple attributes when one of them is shared:

```
scala> val s1=Set("A","B","C")
s1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(A, B, C)

scala> s1.map((a:String)=>{<X w={a}></X>})
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[scala.xml.Elem] = Set(<X w="A"></X>, <X w="B"></X>, <X w="C"></X>)

scala> s1.map((a:String)=>{<X w={a} k="SSS"></X>})
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Set[scala.xml.Elem] = Set(<X k="SSS" w="A"></X>)
```

What happened to B & C?

Or is my understanding of equals on Elems wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does appear to be a bug, albeit a very strange one.  I would guess it's a bug in `Set` and not `Elem`, but I can't speak with any authority on that point.

Comment: And so it is https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4103 , https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3886 apparently fixed in trunk...I suppose I could have looked there first.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in `xml.MetaData` or its subclass `xml.Attribute`. When comparing two `Elem`s, it is checked for equality of the xml prefix, the label, the attributes and the `Node`’s children.

Now, `xml.MetaData` has kind of a strange implementation underneath, it contains itself and at the same time a linked list of attributes. That means that, for example:

```
scala >val elem = <e x="a" y="b"></e>
elem: scala.xml.Elem = <e y="b" x="a"></e>

scala> elem.attributes
res50: scala.xml.MetaData =  y="b" x="a"

scala> elem.attributes.toSet
res51: Set[scala.xml.MetaData] = Set( y="b" x="a",  x="a")
```

E.g. it generates a list of itself with the head attribute removed.

The equality check in `MetaData` looks like this

```
this.toSet == other.toSet
```

which works okay but is overridden in the `Attribute` class. (We can’t see it in the REPL, but our `elem.attributes` really is an `Attribute`.) There, the code only does this

```
(this.pre == other.pre) && (this.key == other.key) && (this.value sameElements other.value)
```

Which would be fine, if the attributes list were converted to a `Set` before but it isn’t and so only the first element in the attributes list is checked for equality. And thus, if the head element in the internal linked list of attributes happens to be the same element for two `xml.Elem`s, they will be equal.

Comment: Oh well, I should’ve searched the ticket db as well before writing all that stuff….